# Kafka Connect Filter Transformer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using a Kafka-connect, and I want to filter out some messages.

This is how a single message in Kafka looks like.

```
{
  "code": 2001,
  "time": 11111111,
  "requestId": "123456789",
  "info": [
    {
      "name": "dan",
      "value": 21
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is how my transformer looks like

```
transforms:
  transforms: FilterByCode
  transforms.FilterByCode.type: io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value
  transforms.FilterByCode.filter.condition: $[?(@.code == 2000)]
  transforms.FilterByCode.filter.type: include
```

I want to filter out the messages that their code value is not 2000.
I tried to few different syntax for the condition, but could not find any that works.
All the messages are transformed, and no one is filtered.

Any ideas on how I should use the syntax for the filtering condition?

Comment: What is this YAML format you've shown? That's not used by Connect API

Comment: @OneCricketeer This is an internal infrastructure. This is working (I wrote my own transformer, but I want to add the Kafka-connect filter condition, that is what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter out all non 2000 codes, try `[?(@.code != 2000)]`
You may test it here - http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/